# Term for replacing characters in a word

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a name for the more general case of "1337 (leet) speak" where you replace some letters in a word with other letters or symbols, as well as numbers while still conveying the original word?

One use case being when posting in a chat room or forum board where they might employ a censorship bot to block out certain offensive words.

Examples:

- @$$  => ass
- shi!t  => shit
- cvnt  => cunt

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261750/is-there-a-term-denoting-the-writing-of-words-using-numbers-instead-of-letters

Comment: How about *mischaracterize?*

Comment: I've recently read a post where they used *bowdlerize* for that purpose. But out of context it might be misunderstood: people might think the word had been replaced by a different word.

Comment: @Jacinto _bowdlerize_ definitely seems the closest so far.. though it seems almost to be a better term for what the chat room bot is doing, rather than my selective character replacement.

Answer (score 1):

The use of censorship or hiding of a word are sometimes called a gawlix. Named after the man who started using them.

Comment: Can you provide any more supporting info on this?  Just did a quick google of "gawlix"... and nothing very obviously related showed up.

Comment: I think perhaps you mean [grawlix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grawlix).

Comment: That name *gawlix* looks like a gawlix, to me - very suspect. Likewise *grawlix*. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of ***substitution cipher***.

M-W:

> **[substitution cipher](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/substitution%20cipher)**
>   *noun*
>
> :  a cipher in which the letters of the plaintext are systematically
>   replaced by substitute letters
>
> **[cipher](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cipher)**
>   *noun, often attributive*
>
> **2 a** :  a method of transforming a text in order to conceal its meaning
>
> a cipher that can't be decoded

It is also sometimes simply just called ***code***.

M-W:

> **[code](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/code)**
>   *noun*
>
> **3 b** :  a system of symbols (as letters or numbers) used to represent assigned and often secret meanings
>
> The message was sent in code.

Comment: The problem is *substitution cipher* is a type of cipher, and a cipher aims at concealing the meaning, which is the opposite of what the OP asks for.

Comment: Yes, @Jacinto. The cipher here is concealing the _meaning_ from the big brother bot.

Comment: Substitution Cipher doesn't really fit because it has ALL letters replaced with new letters/characters.  Thus the original word is no longer discernible.

Comment: @AdamHead, yes! Some letters are replaced by themselves, that's how _this_ cipher works!

Comment: I suppose.  But that's not the general expectation with a Substitution Cipher